# Java Optional - After map operation, return the value from optional object only if IsPresent() is true

Tags: java, java-17

I need to return a String value after the map operation that returns an `Optional` object. The `map` operation in line 4 returns an `Optional<String>` object. I want to return the value in this Optional object, but I should not directly use `get()` to return the value because it can be empty sometimes. I want to check `isPresent()` or something similar before returning the value.

Just so you know, the below code is not completed. I am stuck at line 5 and unsure how to get the returned value from `findFullUrl()` only if available.

```
private String getFinalString() {
    return getOptionalString(map, constant.key1).map(param -> String.format("%s/ABC", param))
            .orElse( getOptionalString(map, constant.key2) 
                     .map(tUrl -> findFullUrl(tUrl)) // I need to return this value only if only available.
                     .isPresent() // I am stuck here. This line is incomplete. Might need to modify.
             );
    }


private Optional<String> getOptionalString(Map<String, string> map, String key){
   //Some code goes here to get the value from a map.
   return Optional.ofNullable(....);
}

private Optional<String> findFullUrl(String val){
   // some logic goes here to build a url
   return Optional.ofNullable(....);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 Java versions tagged?

Comment: @shmosel I removed java-8 tag

Comment: "I need to return this value only if only available." only what is available?

Comment: That's what `orElseNull()`, `orElseThrow()`, `orElseGet()` are for. Choose which one you need.

Comment: What's the point of calling `getOptionalString()` again in the `orElse()`?

Comment: AFAICT `isPresent()` will never be true, unless the second call to `getOptionalString()` returns something, but the first call doesn't.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. If the optional string isn't present you can't map it at all, and if it is present you're mapping it twice. But surely you need to at least *remove* the `isPresent()` call?

Comment: @shmosel.       I have updated the `getOptionalString()` method now. It takes a map and a key and return the value. So in the first time if it cannot find, it try again with another key in the `orElse()`

Comment: @user207421 I have updated the code now. The each time method call it takes different arguments. So `orElse()` should return a different value. But sometimes ´orElse` can return null. So I want to know how to check that before use `get()`

Comment: @Bohemian       I have updated the method with parameters. Sorry for not updating the methods properly. In the first call, it sends one argument. In the second call it sends a different argument. So the second time it may return null sometimes.

Comment: `Optional.map()` is only called if a value is present. It says so in the Javadoc. Does that answer your question? Otherwise you have more explaining to do.

Comment: @user207421   if you see, the map executes another method `map(tUrl -> findFullUrl(tUrl))`. This `findFullUrl`  can return `Optional`. So I want to know how to get this value if it is available. This is why I tried to use `isPresent()` to see if the value available before use ´get()´

Comment: So you need `.map(tUrl -> findFullUrl(tUrl).orElse(tURL))`?

Comment: If `findFullUrl` returns an optional, you need `flatMap` instead of `map`. Besides that, your goal is incomplete “I only want to use the value if present” is understood and already implied by `Optional`’s API. But you have to define what should happen if no value is present. Side note: instead of `String.format("%s/ABC", param)` you can simply write `param + "/ABC"` which is easier to read *and* more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might suit your goal.

Now the second map operation returns the value, and if value is empty or null `map()` returns an empty `Optional` so the call to `orElseThrow()` throws an exception.

If the second call to `getOptionalString()` returns an empty `Optional` works the same way as if the `Optional` is not empty but the call to `findFullUrl()` returns `null` or an empty `String`, so it covers all posibilities.

```
private String getFinalString() {
    return getOptionalString(map, constant.key1).map(param -> String.format("%s/ABC", param))
            .orElse( getOptionalString(map, constant.key2) 
                 .map(tUrl -> return findFullUrl(tUrl))
                     .orElseThrow(CustomException::new)
         );
}
```

If you dont want to throw an `Exception`:

```
private String getFinalString() {
    return getOptionalString(map, constant.key1).map(param -> String.format("%s/ABC", param))
            .orElse( getOptionalString(map, constant.key2) 
                 .map(tUrl -> return findFullUrl(tUrl))
                     .orElse('Default String')
         );
}
```

Comment: Your first example has a bug. Since you're using `orElse`, the value of its argument is always evaluated (though perhaps ignored), meaning that it will crash if the second `Optional` is empty, regardless of whether the first has a value or not. This is the difference between `orElse` and `orElseGet`; the former eagerly evaluates the fallback, the latter doesn't.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic  Why the second `Optional` will crash? Isn't it why it has  another `.orElse('Default String')` to return a default string if the first on is empty ? Do you mean then we can never have ´orElse´ if it returns empty and it will throw exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This is why `or` and `flatMap` are useful:

```java
return getOptionalString(map, constant.key1)
        .map(param -> String.format("%s/ABC", param))
        .or(() -> getOptionalString(map, constant.key2)
                .flatMap(tUrl -> findFullUrl(tUrl))
        )
        .orElseThrow(); // Or whatever else you want in the case neither has a value
```

Here, I've made two changes. Instead of `orElse`, which supplies a `String`, I'm using `or` which supplies an `Optional<String>` and flattens it out into a single `Optional`.

Likewise, inside the `or`, I'm using `flatMap` instead of `map` to make the result an `Optional<String>` instead of an `Optional<Optional<String>>`.

Comment: why I cannot use `orElse()` instead of `or()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or()` to load the second variation lazily in the same chain. You'll also need a nested `flatMap()` because `findFullUrl()` itself returns Optional. Then end the chain with a `orElseNull()` for when there's no result:

```
private String getFinalString() {
    return getOptionalString(map, constant.key1)
            .map(param -> String.format("%s/ABC", param))
            .or(() -> getOptionalString(map, constant.key2).flatMap(this::findFullUrl))
            .orElseNull();
}
```

Comment: if the `getOptionalString(map, constant.key1)` value is not present then it goes to ´or()´? and execute the `getOptionalString(map, constant.key2)` ? Why we cannot use `orElse()` instead of `or()`?
Could you little bit explain why you had to use `flatMap` instead `map()`. Appreciate your reply to these questions. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `orElse()` but then it's calling the second variation unnecessarily when the first is available. A better alternative would be `orElseGet()`, but `or()` is even cleaner here.

Comment: `flatMap()` is necessary when you're mapping to a method that itself returns Optional. Otherwise you end up with `Optional<Optional<String>>`.